# Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

Hola que tal soy nuevo en esto de **JavaScript** espero alguien me pueda ayudar, estoy tratando de importar unos módulos que me ayudaran para comprimir imágenes pero me sale error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Este es mi código:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import ImageCompressor from 'image-compressor.js';

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];

  if (!file) {
    return;
  }

  new ImageCompressor(file, {
    quality: .6,
    success(result) {
      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('files', result, result.name);

      // Send the compressed image file to server with XMLHttpRequest.
      axios.post('/path/to/upload', formData).then(() => {
        console.log('Upload success');
      });
    },
    error(e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="image" multiple="true" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"/>
```

Este es el error que me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

No estoy muy seguro de que sea esto pero trata de poner la ruta de el archivo:

```
import axios from './axios';
import ImageCompressor from './image-compressor';
```

No hace falta que pongas el '.js' por que el sistema de módulos de javascript ya espera que sea un archivo javascript (lo da por hecho).
Dime si te funciona.

Comment: Que tal buenas tarde y gracias por tomarte un tiempo para comentar, y pues ya lo intente, ya puse la ruta del modulo y sigue aun así marcando el mismo error

Comment: Buenas, ¿As exportado bien lo que quieres importar?

Comment: si los módulos ya están correctamente instalados